# Laravel Backpack issue adding route for CRUD controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

For my project I'm using a Laravel backend with Backpack installed. Currently Backpack has generated a CRUD controller for my Role model but I want to add a field. Since this CRUD controller isn't in my project I can't edit this controller. So I wanted to create a new CRUD controller for my Role model. So I ran the following command:

```
php artisan backpack:crud role
```

When it asked for a type I gave `field` as value. When I run this I get an exception as can be seen in the added image.

[image: CLI backpack exception]

I tried using different types (request, etc.) but I got the same exception. I also tried updating Backpack, but this didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your error please have a look at: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/community-forum/discussions/500

The problem is that your `routes/backpack/custom.php` file does not have the expected end line.

To add fields etc in your roles, you can simply create a new `App/RoleController extends Package/RoleController` and then bind your new controller in a ServiceProvider.

Follow the instructions here: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager#customize-usercrudcontroller

Cheers